# Print Permutations of Array in Python

Tags: python, permutation

Apologies in advance as this question has been repeated ad nauseum.

I've banged my head for 3+ hours on what should be simple, but just cannot figure this out.
If anyone can tell me what's going wrong I'll grant you naming rights to my first born.

```
outputs = []
def permutation_helper(available_list, slate):
    if len(available_list) == 0:
        outputs.append(slate)
        return
    for num_idx in range(len(available_list)):
        slate.append(available_list[num_idx])
        if num_idx == len(available_list) - 1:
            permutation_helper(available_list[0:num_idx], slate)
        else:     
            permutation_helper(available_list[0:num_idx] + available_list[num_idx+1:], slate)
        slate = slate[0:len(slate)-1]
slate = []
nums = [1,2,3]
permutation_helper(nums, slate)

print(outputs)
```

Instead of the normal set of permutations, the result is

> [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 2], [1, 2, 2, 1, 3], [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1], [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1]]

I added some print statements when the slate is changed, and it seems like it is being changed two times from [1,2,3] to [1,2] instead of just once.

Code with debugging statements

```
outputs = []
def permutation_helper(available_list, slate):
    print("Starting with available list: " + str(available_list) + "and slate: " + str(slate))
    if len(available_list) == 0:
        print("Adding to output")
        outputs.append(slate)
        return
    for num_idx in range(len(available_list)):
        print("Starting iteration")
        print("Appending " + str(available_list[num_idx]) + " to slate of: " + str(slate))
        slate.append(available_list[num_idx])
        if num_idx == len(available_list) - 1:
            print("Calling last")
            permutation_helper(available_list[0:num_idx], slate)
        else:     
            print("Calling default")
            permutation_helper(available_list[0:num_idx] + available_list[num_idx+1:], slate)
        print("Slate was: " + str(slate) + " and will be: "+ str(slate[0:len(slate)-1]))
        slate = slate[0:len(slate)-1]
        print("Ending iteration with available list of " + str(available_list))
    print("Ending call for available list:  " + str(available_list))
slate = []
nums = [1,2,3]
permutation_helper(nums, slate)
```

Output

```
Starting with available list: [1, 2, 3]and slate: []
Starting iteration
Appending 1 to slate of: []
Calling default
Starting with available list: [2, 3]and slate: [1]
Starting iteration
Appending 2 to slate of: [1]
Calling default
Starting with available list: [3]and slate: [1, 2]
Starting iteration
Appending 3 to slate of: [1, 2]
Calling last
Starting with available list: []and slate: [1, 2, 3]
Adding to output
Slate was: [1, 2, 3] and will be: [1, 2]
Ending iteration with available list of [3]
Ending call for available list:  [3]
Slate was: [1, 2, 3] and will be: [1, 2]
Ending iteration with available list of [2, 3]
Starting iteration
Appending 3 to slate of: [1, 2]
Calling last
Starting with available list: [2]and slate: [1, 2, 3]
Starting iteration
Appending 2 to slate of: [1, 2, 3]
Calling last
Starting with available list: []and slate: [1, 2, 3, 2]
Adding to output
Slate was: [1, 2, 3, 2] and will be: [1, 2, 3]
Ending iteration with available list of [2]
Ending call for available list:  [2]
Slate was: [1, 2, 3, 2] and will be: [1, 2, 3]
Ending iteration with available list of [2, 3]
Ending call for available list:  [2, 3]
Slate was: [1, 2, 3] and will be: [1, 2]
Ending iteration with available list of [1, 2, 3]
Starting iteration
Appending 2 to slate of: [1, 2]
Calling default
Starting with available list: [1, 3]and slate: [1, 2, 2]
Starting iteration
Appending 1 to slate of: [1, 2, 2]
Calling default
Starting with available list: [3]and slate: [1, 2, 2, 1]
Starting iteration
Appending 3 to slate of: [1, 2, 2, 1]
Calling last
Starting with available list: []and slate: [1, 2, 2, 1, 3]
Adding to output
Slate was: [1, 2, 2, 1, 3] and will be: [1, 2, 2, 1]
Ending iteration with available list of [3]
Ending call for available list:  [3]
Slate was: [1, 2, 2, 1, 3] and will be: [1, 2, 2, 1]
Ending iteration with available list of [1, 3]
Starting iteration
Appending 3 to slate of: [1, 2, 2, 1]
Calling last
Starting with available list: [1]and slate: [1, 2, 2, 1, 3]
Starting iteration
Appending 1 to slate of: [1, 2, 2, 1, 3]
Calling last
Starting with available list: []and slate: [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1]
Adding to output
Slate was: [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1] and will be: [1, 2, 2, 1, 3]
Ending iteration with available list of [1]
Ending call for available list:  [1]
Slate was: [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1] and will be: [1, 2, 2, 1, 3]
Ending iteration with available list of [1, 3]
Ending call for available list:  [1, 3]
Slate was: [1, 2, 2, 1, 3] and will be: [1, 2, 2, 1]
Ending iteration with available list of [1, 2, 3]
Starting iteration
Appending 3 to slate of: [1, 2, 2, 1]
Calling last
Starting with available list: [1, 2]and slate: [1, 2, 2, 1, 3]
Starting iteration
Appending 1 to slate of: [1, 2, 2, 1, 3]
Calling default
Starting with available list: [2]and slate: [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1]
Starting iteration
Appending 2 to slate of: [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1]
Calling last
Starting with available list: []and slate: [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2]
Adding to output
Slate was: [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2] and will be: [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1]
Ending iteration with available list of [2]
Ending call for available list:  [2]
Slate was: [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2] and will be: [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1]
Ending iteration with available list of [1, 2]
Starting iteration
Appending 2 to slate of: [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1]
Calling last
Starting with available list: [1]and slate: [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2]
Starting iteration
Appending 1 to slate of: [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2]
Calling last
Starting with available list: []and slate: [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1]
Adding to output
Slate was: [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1] and will be: [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2]
Ending iteration with available list of [1]
Ending call for available list:  [1]
Slate was: [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1] and will be: [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2]
Ending iteration with available list of [1, 2]
Ending call for available list:  [1, 2]
Slate was: [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2] and will be: [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1]
Ending iteration with available list of [1, 2, 3]
Ending call for available list:  [1, 2, 3]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 2], [1, 2, 2, 1, 3], [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1], [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, I think you are trying to replicate the Heap's algorithm for permutations. Why don't you compare with the [original](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/heaps-algorithm-for-generating-permutations/) to find your differences?
Also duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60975877/implementing-heaps-algorithm-for-permutations-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry for you, indeed this a head-banging bug.
The problem lies in the interaction between 2 aspects of Python : the local/global scopes, and the mutable/immutable references.
Both are tricky in isolation, combined they are nasty.

What happens is that you have a global variable named `slate`, exactly like the `slate` argument of your function, also exactly like the `slate` variable declared with `slate = slate[0:len(slate)-1]`.
What is especially disturbing is that on this line :

```py
slate = slate[0:len(slate)-1]
```

both `slate`s are not the same references ... not all the time ...
Let me explain with a (not that much) simpler example inspired by your code :

```py
from typing import List, Any


def my_function(mutable_arg: List[Any], level: int = 0):
    indent_str = ' |' * level
    print(indent_str, f"{id(mutable_arg)=!r} {mutable_arg=!r}")
    if level >= 2:
        return
    else:
        for x in ('a', 'b',):
            print(indent_str, f"currently at {level=!r} calling subfunction")
            mutable_arg.append(x + str(level))
            my_function(mutable_arg, level=level+1)
            print(indent_str, f"back at {level=!r}")
            print(indent_str, f"{id(mutable_arg)=!r} {mutable_arg=!r} before pop")
            mutable_arg = mutable_arg[:len(mutable_arg)-1]
            print(indent_str, f"{id(mutable_arg)=!r} {mutable_arg=!r} after pop")


mutable_arg = []  # whatever
print(f"top-level {id(mutable_arg)=!r} {mutable_arg=!r}")
my_function(mutable_arg)
```

it produces (with my manual annotations) :

```
top-level id(mutable_arg)=140026485211520 mutable_arg=[]       # here we have our initial list id=...1520
#                                    ^^^^
 id(mutable_arg)=140026485211520 mutable_arg=[]                # the reference is passed to the function (in other languages, we call that "pass by reference")
 currently at level=0 calling subfunction
 | id(mutable_arg)=140026485211520 mutable_arg=['a0']          # still the same
 | currently at level=1 calling subfunction
 | | id(mutable_arg)=140026485211520 mutable_arg=['a0', 'a1']  # still the same
 | back at level=1
 | id(mutable_arg)=140026485211520 mutable_arg=['a0', 'a1'] before pop  # still the same
 | id(mutable_arg)=140026485571904 mutable_arg=['a0'] after pop  # here it changes !! it becomes id=...1904 !
#                             ^^^^
 | currently at level=1 calling subfunction
 | | id(mutable_arg)=140026485571904 mutable_arg=['a0', 'b1']    # stays at the new value id=1904
 | back at level=1
 | id(mutable_arg)=140026485571904 mutable_arg=['a0', 'b1'] before pop  # stays
 | id(mutable_arg)=140026485939904 mutable_arg=['a0'] after pop  # another new value ! id=...9904
#                             ^^^^
 back at level=0
 id(mutable_arg)=140026485211520 mutable_arg=['a0', 'a1'] before pop  # and here is initial value again ! id=...1520
 id(mutable_arg)=140026485939904 mutable_arg=['a0'] after pop  # but it changes immediatly to id=...9904
[...snip]
```

At first, because Python is *pass-by-reference* for **mutable** objects (like `list`s), the function receives a reference to the list defined at the top-level (global) scope.
But when we encounter the `mutable_arg = mutable_arg[...]` for the first time, the (right-side) `mutable_arg` still not exists in the local scope so Python grabs the global reference. Then `mutable_arg[:len(mutable_arg)-1]` returns a new reference (a **slice**). But when we assign it to (left-side) `mutable_arg` then Python stores it in the local scope (which is the current function call execution). So effectively, this line creates a different copy of `mutable_arg`.
On the following iterations, each time `mutable_arg` is referenced, Python finds it in the local scope so it does not use the global one anymore. From there, we are effectively working on a branched-off version. In itself, it would not be a problem, but the caller expects `mutable_arg` to be in the same state as before the call (*unchecked invariant*). But because of the branching, the last element was removed only in the copy only, not in the original.
Hence the diverging.

The fix is simply to change the line to :

```py
- slate = slate[0:len(slate)-1]
+ slate.pop()
```

That way, it always operates on the same reference, it never creates a new one, so `slate` can't diverge.

Another solution is to `copy` the `slate`s before passing them to the sub-functions :

```py
permutation_helper(available_list[0:num_idx], slate.copy())
#                                                  ^^^^^^^
permutation_helper(available_list[0:num_idx] + available_list[num_idx+1:], slate.copy())
#                                                                               ^^^^^^^
```